# Slow and fast comparison in Tablediff.exe

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using tablediff.exe to compare two SQL tables, on two servers one is local and the other is remote.
My first table is Table1 (380,000 records)
My second Table is Table2 (290,000 records)

When I compare local Table1 to remote Table1 it takes about 6 minutes .

When I compare local Table2 to remote Table2 it takes about forever and no result (Table2 has less records than Table1)

I deleted a column of type image from Table2, but the problem still there.

What may be the problem ?

NOTE: TABLE2 Structure

```
[ID] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
[Title] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[FName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[MName] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
[LName] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
[MotherName] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
[DOB] [datetime] NULL,
[BirthPlace] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Gender] [varchar](1) NULL,
[MaritalStatus] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
[ChildrenNo] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Occupation] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
[NationalityID] [varchar](3) NULL,
[Address] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Telephone] [varchar](20) NULL,
[Mobile] [varchar](20) NULL,
[Email] [varchar](50) NULL,
[BloodGroup] [varchar](3) NULL,
[RecieveSMS] [bit] NULL,
[FileNo] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
[PrimaryPhysician] [varchar](10) NULL,
[IqamaID] [varchar](10) NULL,
[EmergencyContactName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[EmergencyContactRelation] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[EmergencyContactNo] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[ProfilePicture] [image] NULL,
[Status] [bit] NULL,
[SecondaryTelNo] [varchar](20) NULL,
[SecondaryMobileNo] [varchar](20) NULL,
[Notes] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[BankID] [varchar](10) NULL,
[IBANNo] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[isWalkIn] [bit] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Patients_isWalkIn]  DEFAULT ((0)),
[AR_FName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[AR_MName] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
[AR_LName] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
[AR_MotherName] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
[isVIP] [bit] NULL,
[FirstVisitDate] [varchar](255) NULL,
[EmploymentID] [varchar](20) NULL,
[ImagePath] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
[PatientLevel] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Patients_PatientLevel]  DEFAULT ((1)),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Patients] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: It could depend on a lot of things. How you're comparing them, what's your data like, how are your indexes, etc. Could you provide a data sample or at least a schema of your Table2? More information is needed in order to be able to help you out.

Comment: Can you also tell us how exactly do you compare them? Just by IDs or you're comparing whether a whole row is the same in both tables? This is a possible huge bottleneck.

Comment: I am using tablediff.exe, it is comparing the whole rows..I am wondering why Table1 is taking less time even  though it is bigger and I am using the same comparison tool.

Comment: Do you have enough permissions on these databases to rebuild the index that I see is on the ID column? Also, is the clustered index on *Table1* also of varchar type?

Comment: Yes i am logging in as sa , and yes it is a varchar(10)

Comment: One more comment : If I take the same DB (backup from the client's server) and restored on my PC and compare it to the same table on the same DB on the same remote server as above, it takes about 6 minutes !

Comment: Might really be the indexes. Can you rebuild the indexes on both servers?

Comment: @MK_ How to to that?

Comment: Sorry for a late reply. Follow these instructions: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187874(v=sql.105).aspx